# How to setup H2 for Corda

Tags: corda

I am re-writing and running a IssueFlow for an example cordapp [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example). 
I can see the flow is successful and can find a number of UTXOs on the vault query for the node.

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.example.state.IOUStat
```

I would like to view the data in the persistent store (H2).

I've added the following to my node's config (similar for party A node with different port).

```
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
p2pAddress="localhost:10008"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10009"
    adminAddress="localhost:10049"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }   
}

h2Settings {
    address: "localhost:12344"
}
```

I can see the DB url on run-nodes

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:12344/node
```

I can successfully connect to this db url. However , I do not see any tables for my Persistent state

[DB Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFa9Y.png)

```
object IOUSchema

object IOUSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
        schemaFamily = IOUSchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes =  listOf(PersistentIOU::class.java)){

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "iou_states")
    class PersistentIOU(
            @Column(name = "lender")
            var lenderName : String,

            @Column (name = "borrower")
            var borrowerName : String,

            @Column(name = "value")
            var value : Int,

            @Column(name = "linear_id")
            var linearId : UUID

    ) : PersistentState(){
        constructor() : this("","",0, UUID.randomUUID())
    }
}



@BelongsToContract(IOUContract::class)
data class IOUState (val value : Int,
                     val lender: Party,
                     val borrower : Party,
                     override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()): LinearState, QueryableState {

    override val participants : List<AbstractParty> get() = listOf(lender,borrower)

    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        return when (schema){
            is IOUSchemaV1 -> IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU(
                    this.lender.name.toString(),
                    this.borrower.name.toString(),
                    this.value,
                    this.linearId.id
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
        }
    }

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(IOUSchemaV1)

}
```

EDIT: This certainly works by connecting directly to the file. See [here](https://docs.corda.net/node-database-access-h2.html), However this looks like it is connecting to a different db when using a external client (dbeaver) to connect to the JDBC url emmited on node startup.

Comment: Did you add `generateMappedObject()` (https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/contracts-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/state/IOUState.kt#L33) and `supportedSchemas()` (https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/contracts-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/state/IOUState.kt#L45) to your state?

Comment: @AdelRustum Updated post to show my state class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find tables in H2 instance as my connection string was wrong & H2 appears is creating a blank db when trying to connect to a non-existant DB.

In DBeaver , you can add the JDBC url, but it automatically pre-fixes 'jdbc:h2:'

[Connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN1xu.png)